# "," вместо "." в Double

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Я новичок в swift и пытаюсь написать приложение - калькулятор. Возможно мой вопрос может показаться глупым, но все же

При создании числа с точкой я хочу, что бы в строке выводилось число с "," (что то типа `3,14`), но swift (используя тип `Double`) по умолчанию выводит число как `3.14`.
Можно ли это изменить? Нужно ли для этого прибегать к `NumberFormatter()` и если да, то как правильно его использовать?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1412937-replacingoccurrences

Comment: Наверное этот символ (`,` для русского, `.` для каких-то других языков) должен определяться текущим значением [decimalSeparator](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nslocale/1643064-decimalseparator) в [NSLocale](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nslocale).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1 - Используя NumberFormatter

```
let pi: Double = 3.14

let numFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal // устанавливаем стиль - десятичный
numFormatter.decimalSeparator = "," // устанавливаем десятичный разделитель

let piStr = numFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: pi))!
print(piStr) // 3,14
```

Вариант 2 - Используя замену символа в строке

```
let pi: Double = 3.14

var piStr = String(pi)
piStr = piStr.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ",") // заменяем символ '.' на ','
print(piStr) // 3,14
```